# Andengine Parallax Background

Tags: java, android, andengine

Background:
I am making a 2D side-scroller.
When the player touches the screen, the player moves forward (the camera follows the player).

I cannot find an answer to this question although it seems rather straightforward.

Question:
How can I get my parallax background to scroll only when my player moves?
(example code would make things much easier for me)

I am using autoparallaxbackground but it seems that it simply just scrolls at the rates you pass in, with no regard to the camera. Moreover, I am not fully sure of the difference between autoparallaxbackground and parallaxbackground.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoParallaxBackground` extends `ParallaxBackground`, adding one simple feature: automatically changing `mParallaxValue` with time. As you may imagine, if you don't need your background constantly moving, you may use `ParallaxBackground` as your base class, and then use `setParallaxValue(final float pParallaxValue)` to manually adjust the position.

Comment: I am confused by the parameter 'pParallaxValue'.  How does this value translate to a position?  How would that value be related to the position of the camera (as I explained)? Thanks.

Comment: there are two parameters which control the background position, the first one is `parallaxValue`, and another is `parallaxFactor`, the pixel position of background is calculated by multiplying them. most probably the `parallaxFactor` allows for several backgrounds moving with different speeds. you may try to change values and see what happens.

Comment: your answer is still a little vague.  could you maybe give a concrete example? ive seen everything you're describing in the engine source code, but i dont understand exactly how the parallaxValue/Factor translates to a "pixel position"

Comment: the answer to your question "How can I get my parallax background to scroll only when my player moves?" is "when you move your player and want the background to scroll, change `mParallaxValue` the way you like"

Comment: i understand this. but could you explain what passing in an arbitrary float (say .5f) to setParallaxValue() means in terms of the the position of the background? since i dont understand that, i cant simply "change mParallaxValue the way I like".

Comment: please, look at the sources you said you have: `float baseOffset = (pParallaxValue * this.mParallaxFactor);` calculates the offset, which is passed then to `pGL.glTranslatef(baseOffset, 0, 0);` -- i don't know how more detailed of specific this can be. if you pass .5f go `setParallaxValue()`, it means your background gets shifted `0.5 * parallaxFactor` to the left.